# R: Replace NA resulting from joining but not NA in original row

Tags: r

Let's say I have to dataframes:

```
weights <- tibble(Time = c(as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 10:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 13:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 14:00:00")), weight = c(3, NA, 4), is_weight = c(1, 1, 1))
heights <- tibble(Time = c(as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 11:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 12:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 15:00:00")), height = c(4, NA, 5), is_height = c(1, 1, 1))
```

After joining them by Time and filling NAs in the `is_<>` cols, I get

```
df <- full_join(weights, heights, by = "Time") %>% arrange(Time) %>% mutate(is_weight = replace(is_weight, is.na(is_weight), 0)) %>% mutate(is_height = replace(is_height, is.na(is_height), 0))
 df
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Time                weight is_weight height is_height
  <dttm>               <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1 1900-01-01 10:00:00      3         1     NA         0
2 1900-01-01 11:00:00     NA         0      4         1
3 1900-01-01 12:00:00     NA         0     NA         1
4 1900-01-01 13:00:00     NA         1     NA         0
5 1900-01-01 14:00:00      4         1     NA         0
6 1900-01-01 15:00:00     NA         0      5         1
```

Now, there are to types of `NAs`. That is, in the third row, height is `NA` because it comes from the original data, i.e. we really have no value at this time. However, in row 4, `height` is `NA` because of the joining operation. Same goes for `weight`. What I want: I want to keep the "original" NA, and only fill the NAs resulting from the joining operation with the previous value when possible. For example for `weight`, whenever `is_weight = 0`, I want to copy the value of `weight` from the last column where `is_weight = 1`. Same for height.

```
Time                      weight is_weight height is_height
      <dttm>               <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
    1 1900-01-01 10:00:00      3         1     NA         0
    2 1900-01-01 11:00:00      3         0      4         1
    3 1900-01-01 12:00:00      3         0     NA         1
    4 1900-01-01 13:00:00     NA         1     NA         0
    5 1900-01-01 14:00:00      4         1     NA         0
    6 1900-01-01 15:00:00      4         0      5         1
```

So with this I want to ensure that at every timstep, I have the last received value of each variable. Is there a neat generic way that I can also apply on let's say 10 columns?

My idea was to replace the "original" NA with some value like `1234`, then use `fill` method after joing and replace `1234` back to `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

With `match` + `fill`:

```r
df %>% 
  fill(weight) %>% 
  mutate(weight = ifelse(!is.na(match(Time, weights$Time)) & is.na(weights$weight[match(df$Time, weights$Time)]), NA, weight))

  Time                weight is_weight height is_height
  <dttm>               <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1 1900-01-01 10:00:00      3         1     NA         0
2 1900-01-01 11:00:00      3         0      4         1
3 1900-01-01 12:00:00      3         0     NA         1
4 1900-01-01 13:00:00     NA         1     NA         0
5 1900-01-01 14:00:00      4         1     NA         0
6 1900-01-01 15:00:00      4         0      5         1
```